# Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a button that should be very big. It has to have a text on the left, a picture in the middle and an arrow on the right side.

[This is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrTF3.png)

I've tried everything to put the initial text on the left side, it doesn't work.
Does anybody have any experience with this?

This is what my code looks like:

```css
.framework-title {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-framework {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn-framework:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(90%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(90%);
  -o-filter: brightness(90%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(90%);
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-framework" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#framework1" tyle="text-align:left !important; padding-left:6px !important;">
                                          
    <span class="framework-title text-align:left !important; padding-left:6px !important;">Phase</span> 
    <img src="images/analyze/1_phase.png" width="800px" style="margin-right: 0px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="vertical-align: middle;"></span>
        
</button>
```

Comment: have you tried float. float:right ?

Comment: Is this button going to be responsive? I ask because I see that you're setting the image width explicitly to be 800px wide. On small devices that won't work so well.

Answer (score 0):

You could float it left and right? not exactly sure what you want :-D

```css
.framework-title {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
}
.btn-framework {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
 
}

.glyphicon-menu-right {float:right;}

.btn-framework:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(90%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(90%);
    -o-filter: brightness(90%);
    -ms-filter: brightness(90%);
    filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-framework" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#framework1" tyle="text-align:left !important; padding-left:6px !important;">

<span class="framework-title text-align:left !important; padding-left:6px !important;">Phase</span> 
<img src="images/analyze/1_phase.png" width="800px" style="margin-right: 0px;" alt="image1">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="vertical-align: middle;"></span>

</button>
```